# How to release process resource in java

Tags: java

How to release process resource??

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class RuntimeSample{
    public RuntimeSample() {
    }
    private void execCmd1() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        Process process = null;
        String[] cmd = { "java", "-version" };
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            in = process.getInputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    } 
    private void execCmd2() throws IOException {
        Process process = null;
        String[] cmd = { "java", "-version" };
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

why it is throwing process.getError stream is not closed,I tried to close process resource by using following

```
if (process != null) {
    process.getInputStream().close();
    process.getOutputStream().close();
    process.getErrorStream().close();
```

even it is showing process.getError stream is not closed.may i know the reason y it is showing that stream is not closed and how to close the process resource.Thanks in advance

Comment: Some indentation would enhance readability.

Comment: What error do you get (stacktrace please)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is somewhat late, but maybe someone else runs into the same issue.

In my project the Server runs some utility (I call it winps.exe here) regularly and it was easy to see (using RAMMAP resp. Handles) that the Java process kept a handle to each of the (terminated) child processes. Restarting the Server removed all entries from the process table.

After some experimenting, I found that explicitly calling the Garbage Collector resolved the issue.

Below you find my Java test program which I used to investigate the matter.
Note that this test program has been copied from the Server source code and isn't 100% as cleanly written as possible.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class StartPS
{
        static Long STARTTIME_JITTER = 5000L;

        synchronized public static HashMap<String,Long> getStartTimes()
        {
                HashMap<String,Long> result = new HashMap<String, Long>();;
                final File tmp_file = new File("/tmp/starttimes.out");
                String tmpfilename = null;
                try {
                        tmpfilename = tmp_file.getCanonicalPath();
                } catch (Exception e) {}

                try {
                        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(".\\winps.exe");

                        pb.redirectOutput(new File(tmpfilename));
                        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                        Process p = pb.start();
                        p.getOutputStream().close();
                        p.getInputStream().close();
                        p.getErrorStream().close();
                        try {
                                p.waitFor();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                                // maybe some cleanup here
                        }

                        try {
                                while (p.isAlive()) { // <- most likely unnecessary ;-)
                                        Thread.sleep(100);
                                        p.destroy();
                                        System.gc();
                                }
                                p = null;      // should help the garbage collector (eliminates a reference to the object p points to)
                                System.gc();   // <- most likely the key to success !
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Warning: " + e.toString());
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("(02310251044) Process start times : " + e.toString());
                }
                return result;
        }

        public static void main(String[] argv)
        {
                String sMax;
                int iMax = 500;

                if  (argv.length > 0) {
                        sMax = argv[0];
                        try {
                                iMax = Integer.parseInt(sMax);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Oops : " + e.toString());
                                System.exit(1);
                        }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < iMax; ++i) {
                        System.out.print("\r" + i);
                        getStartTimes();
                        try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                // do nothing
                        }
                }
        }

}
```